LaTeX labels propositions as Theorems in text instead of Propositions
I have the following simple example in LaTeX:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% Theorem environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

% Cleveref configuration
\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{theorems}
\crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{propositions}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{1}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
\label{2}
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}

Refer to \cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\end{document}

It outputs this:

You can see that it labels Proposition 2 as Theorem 2 in text. I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is. I'm not quite sure if it's an issue with cleveref, or maybe I did something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Interesting. With a current LaTeX I get ?? and a warning cref reference format for label type ' undefined` (also verified on texlive.net) but with a slightly older LaTeX (overleaf texlive 2024) I get your output. In any case, it does the right thing if you load amsthm, but of course then the theorem formatting will change

Changes were made to the kernel \newtheorem on 2024/03/18 but overleaf uses LaTeX from 2024-03-14

@mbert I tried with older versions of TeX Live and the result is always “Theorem 2”.

I assume you're not, but just in case (or for others): don't use 1 and 2 as your actual labels.

@egreg I wasn't trying to say that the output is correct in older formats. I was trying to figure out why there is no output at all (or rather ??) with a current format

@mbert Yes, that's interesting.

@egreg There's already an open issue: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1393

I'm not sure where the bug is, but if you load amsthm, the problem vanishes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}

% Theorem environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

% Cleveref configuration
%\crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{theorems}
%\crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{propositions}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{1}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
\label{2}
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}

Refer to \cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\end{document}



It also works with ntheorem, but I don't recommend it.

+1. If one uses ntheorem instead of amsthm, it's advisable to load it with the options amsmath and thmmarks (since amsmath is being loaded as well).

this worked, thank you so much!

If you want to use the kernel's \newtheorem, this situation is explicitly mentioned in the cleveref documentation, pages 9-10. It gives the following workaround using aliascnt.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{proposition}{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[proposition]{Proposition}
\aliascntresetthe{proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\label{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}
\label{prop}
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}

Refer to \cref{thm} and \cref{prop}.

\end{document}

Note this only works with a LaTeX format 2023-03-14 or older. Changes were made to \newtheorem in the meantime that seem to break cleveref support.
